# Is it possible in CucumberJs & Cypress to make contexts independent and allow steps with same description?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, definition, cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I've a Cypress and CucumberJs setup based on typescript for end to end tests in a project I'm working on.

It happens to have two different feature files `bus.feature` and `car.feature` with their step definition files `bus.spec.ts` and `car.spec.ts`

I've two different step definitions:

```
Then(
  'I {string} the Destination page', (operation: operation) => {
    cy.location().should(location => {
      switch (operation) {
        case 'visit':
          expect(location.pathname).to.eq('/e2e/destination')
          break

        case `can't visit`:
          expect(location.pathname).to.eq('/e2e/bus')
          break
      }
    })
  }
)
```

and

```
Then(
  'I {string} the Destination page', (operation: operation) => {
    cy.location().should(location => {
      switch (operation) {
        case 'visit':
          expect(location.pathname).to.eq('/e2e/destination')
          break

        case `can't visit`:
          expect(location.pathname).to.eq('/e2e/car')
          break
      }
    })
  }
)
```

identical in their recognitional string `'I {string} the Destination page'` but slightly different in the implementation (for instance the case `can't visit`).

When I run the tests, the `bus` one is fully executed perfectly.

The `car` one has an issue because, being the recognitional string the same for both tests, the Cypress+CucumberJs suite detect just the first `bus` definition, ignoring the `car` and proper one.

I understand why, the first one is detected and that's it.
Question is, is there a way to separate contexts of different files, so being able to have also same definition name with different implementation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```js
'I {string} the Destination page for {string}', (operation: operation, transportMode) => {
  ...
  expect(location.pathname).to.eq(`/e2e/car${transportMode}`)
```

or does that mess up the matching between feature and step?

Comment: Ah it could work. But this is a hook. Maybe conceptually I'm trying to achieve something wrong. But I was wondering if there were different approaches more configuration-wise.